# how to reset host in dotnet nuke

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke

is there any solution to reset the host username and password in dotnet nuke.unfortunately i deleted it from the database.Can any one tell me where the host name and password is storing in nuke table..

Answer (score 3):

You can recreate a user and set its IsSuperUser flag to true in the db. If you want, you can even edit any user whose password you know in order to set it as host

Comment: in which table actually the host details stored?the username is in estore_user table,whr s the password is storing?

Comment: Password is in the aspnetmembership tables.  Just make a new user on the site. Or if you know any other user ... edit the estore_user or User table and set issuperuser = true.  You can try to alter it in aspnetmembership area but you have to deal with encrypted password and salts.